# C++ struct char array initialization

Tags: c++, arduino

```
struct Label {
    char *string;
    int mode;
};
```

I have char pointer in my struct. *string must be initialized on create as char[10] without using malloc-like functions (arduino project with limited memory). I can simply change struct body to

```
struct Label {
    char string[10];
    int mode;
};
```

but also I need to set label.string = "asd" many times with different string size. How to solve this?

Comment: I am a little confused on what exactly the problem you are having is, can you clarify?

Comment: Do you really need to use `label.string = "asd";` or simply copy a null-terminated byte string into the array?

Comment: If you are only setting it to const strings, just use the pointer.

Comment: Structs are fixed size, so just accept there is going to be some waste, and max string length. Beware buffer overflow!

Comment: I need both: using new struct variable as a struct with initialized char array inside which I can change to pointer to const string. Simple way is to use struct from first code example and initialize "string" as a pointer to char array, but, for example, if I have 2 Label vars in main it must be initialized like there were structs with fixed size array inside, because I can't use dynamic memory allocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the only way I know to do this is to store char pointer, which is set to static-allocated array pointer by default and can be changed on runtime:

```
struct Label {
    char stringArray[4];
    char *string = stringArray;
    int mode;
};

int main() {
    Label label;
    label.stringArray[0] = 'a';
    label.stringArray[1] = 'b';
    label.stringArray[2] = 'c';
    label.stringArray[3] = '\0';
    cout << label.string << endl;
    label.string = "bbbbbb";
    cout << label.string << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially fill the `label.string` with a null terminated string value using the `snprintf` function.

Examples:

```
    snprintf(label.string, 10, "asd" );
    snprintf(label.string, 10, "%c%c%c", 'a','s','d');
    snprintf(label.string, sizeof(label.string), "%s%d", "asd", 1);
```

It essentially works like normal `printf` function but the first two arguments specify the destination buffer and the size of this buffer. When you try to copy a string exceeding the boundaries of that buffer, the copied string will be truncated to fit the buffer. Remember the second argument should not be greater then the actual buffer size because you can end up overwriting some other memory region.

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/